# SQL query to get all dependencies of needed DLLs

Tags: sql, ms-access, dependencies

I'm trying to manage my application's dependencies in an Access database, and I could use help with a SQL query to give me back a list of every component as a single result.

For example, suppose I have the following three tables with additional columns that aren't shown here:

```
CurrentBuild      Versions          Dependencies
==============    ==============    =======================================
Item   Version    Item   Version    Item    Version  Dependency  DepVersion
------ -------    ------ -------    ------  -------  ----------  ----------
MyExe  1.3        MyExe  1.0        MyExe   1.0      N/A         N/A
MyDll1 1.0        MyExe  1.1        MyExe   1.1      N/A         N/A
MyDll2 1.0        MyExe  1.2        MyExe   1.2      N/A         N/A
MyDll3 1.1        MyExe  1.3        MyExe   1.3      N/A         N/A
                  MyExe  1.4        MyDll1  1.0      MyDll4      1.0
                  MyDll1 1.0        MyDll2  1.0      SomeMsDll   1.0
                  MyDll2 1.0        MyDll3  1.0      MyDll4      1.0
                  MyDll2 1.1        MyDll3  1.0      MyDll5      1.0
                  MyDll3 1.0        MyDll3  1.1      MyDll4      1.0
                  MyDll3 1.1        MyDll4  1.0      MyDll6      1.0
                  MyDll4 1.0        MyDll5  1.0      MyDll6      1.0
                  MyDll5 1.0        MyDll6  1.0      MyDll7      1.0
                  MyDll6 1.0        MyDll7  1.0      MyDll8      1.0
                  MyDll7 1.0
```

What query can I use to get the following result from the CurrentBuild table? I would prefer a simple query over a VBA macro; however, I'm not opposed to a VBA macro if it can't be done with a query.

```
Item        Version
----------- -------
MyExe       1.3
MyDll1      1.0
MyDll2      1.0
MyDll3      1.1
MyDll4      1.0
MyDll6      1.0
MyDll7      1.0
MyDll8      1.0
SomeMsDll   1.0
```

So far, I have the following, but this doesn't give me the desired results; it just gives me back the contents of the CurrentBuild table:

```
SELECT W.Item, W.Version
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT V.[Item], V.[Version]
   FROM ([Versions] AS V
   INNER JOIN [Dependencies] AS D ON V.[Item] = D.[Dependency] AND V.[Version] = D.[DepVersion])
   INNER JOIN [CurrentBuild] AS S ON D.[Item] = S.[Item] AND D.[Version] = S.[Version]

   UNION

   SELECT DISTINCT V.[Item], V.[Item]
   FROM [Versions] AS V
   INNER JOIN [CurrentBuild] AS S ON V.[Item] = S.[Item] AND V.[Version] = S.[Version])  AS W;
```

In case you're curious why MyExe doesn't have dependencies on the MyDlls, the simple answer is that it's not needed to answer the question about my query; however, FYI, the DLLs are loaded dynamically, so MyExe has no build-time dependency on the MyDlls.

Thanks.

Comment: It would help to provide a comment when voting down a question. In what way(s) does this question not show any research effort, is unclear or not useful? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pack that sucker into a UNION query and just grab the max Version values for each item:

```
SELECT Max(Item) as Item, Max(Version) as Version
FROM
(SELECT Item, Version
FROM CurrentBuild

UNION

SELECT Item, Version
FROM Versions

UNION

SELECT Item, Version
FROM Dependencies

UNION

SELECT Dependency as Item,  DepVersion as Version
FROM Dependencies) AllItem

GROUP BY Item, Version
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, but I'm afraid this won't work for me. I clarified the example above to include additional versions beyond what I need in the CurrentBuild table (MyExe 1.4 and MyDll2 1.1), so I can't just grab the max version. Also the inner SELECT query above seems to work fine, but when I try the entire query, I get the following error: Circular reference caused by alias 'Item' in query definition's SELECT list.

Comment: Trying to inner join isn't going to work, because some items don't have dependencies and vice-versa.  Your best bet is to just get one long list and then take the max version for that item.  You may have to play with the syntax a bit, but it's the right idea.